# How to reduce canvas stroke with animation

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to add some animation on changing the endAngle of a canvas arc like this but it is not working. How can I do this?

```js
var steps =30;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 75;
var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 1.4999 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
context.lineWidth = 15;

context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();

setTimeout(function(){ 
  endAngle = endAngle - 1;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.stroke();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## new answer

Whenever you draw something on the canvas it doesn't erase what was previously drawn on it. You have to do that manually like this:

```
context.fillStyle="#ffffff";
context.fillRect(0,0,250,250);
//draw here
```

full solution:

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
<script language=javascript>

var steps =30;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 75;
var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 1.49 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
context.lineWidth = 15;

context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();

setInterval(function(){ 
  context.fillStyle="#ffffff";
  context.fillRect(0,0,250,250);
  endAngle = endAngle - 0.01;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.stroke();
}, 10);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

## old answer

---

Well there are a few things. You've got your clockwise and counterclockwise mixed up causing the circle to be completely full before your "animation" starts.

if you want it clockwise then put the end angle ahead like this:

```
var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 1.51 * Math.PI;
```

And then increase the angle in your animation timeout instead of decrease:

```
endAngle = endAngle+1;
```

and finally, your timeout should be an interval, not a timeout. The timeout will only run once. simple as changing it to

```
setInterval(function(){...
```

You also don't need jquery for this code by the way.

Comment: Thanks davethecross for the comments but as I said I would like to decrease the circle! what is happening now it is increasing by `endAngle = endAngle+1;`

Comment: Thanks but how can break the drawing after ending the Arc?

Comment: how to stop the animation? You clear the interval. You start by adding


var interval=setInterval(....

and when you want to clear it you call clearInterval(interval);

if you want to clear it when the circle is finished drawing, there are many solutions. What comes to mind immediately is

if(endAngle<-(startAngle)){... or something like that